# Definition of sufficient statistic when the support of the statistic depends on the unknown parameter?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics

Suppose we have a random vector $\mathbf{X} = (X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ or sample with pdf or pmf $f(\mathbf{x};\theta)$, where $\theta \in \Theta$ is an unknown parameter (or vector of parameters), whose specification completely determines $f(\mathbf{x};\theta)$.

As far as I understand, a *statistic* is just a a random variable $T=T(\mathbf{x})$ that is a function (that does not depend on $\theta$) of $\mathbf{X}$. That's not to say the distribution of $T$ doesn't depend on $\theta$ of course, just that the function that relates $\mathbf{X}$ and $T$ does not.

Now, usually from what I've seen, the statistic $T$ is defined to be a *sufficient statistic* if the distribution of $\mathbf{X}$ conditional on $T=t$ does not depend on $\theta$.

**Now, my issue with this definition (which I don't understand how is it not addressed anywhere I've looked) is that if the support of $T$ depends on $\theta$, then we can't really pick a $t$ in the support of $T$ and then claim that the conditional distribution does not depend on $\theta$, because that same conditional distribution may be ill-defined for some values of $\theta$ for which $t$ is not in the support of $T$, right?**

I kinda came up with my own definition which I'm hoping someone could comment on to see if this is what's more formally meant by that usual definition:

A statistic $T(\mathbf{X})$ is sufficient for $\theta$ if there exists a non-negative function $C:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that does not depend on $\theta$ and such that 
$$p(\mathbf{x},t;\theta) = C(\mathbf{x},t) \cdot q(t;\theta)$$
for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n, t\in \mathbb{R}, \theta \in \Theta$, where $p$ and $q$ denote the joint pdf/pmf of $(\mathbf{X},T(\mathbf{X}))$ and the pdf/pmf of $T(\mathbf{X})$, respectively.

Comment: (a) You're welcome to invent any kind of definition you want, but a definition by itself is without any utility.  What matters is *what you can use your definition for.* Yours does not deserve to be called a "sufficient statistic" until you can show that all--or at least most--of the important properties and theorems enjoyed by sufficient statistics also hold for your definition. (b) I cannot make sense of the paragraph about "my issue." Could you elaborate on what you think the problem is?  Perhaps offer a simple example?

Comment: Sure, for instance, consider $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ to be iid variables following a uniform distribution on the interval $[0,\theta]$. Now, if we consider the statistic $T(X_1,\ldots,X_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, then it's clear that the support of $T$ is $[0,n\theta]$, which clearly depends on $\theta$. Now, if I pick any $t$, even if $t>0$, then how can I claim the conditional distribution of $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ conditional on $T=t$ is a constant function of $\theta$, if that conditional distribution isn't even defined for, say $\theta = \frac{t}{2n}$?

Comment: I claim it's not defined because $\theta = t/(2n)$ should imply $T = t = 2n\theta$ is impossible and hence the pdf of $T$ at that point is 0.

Comment: Or better yet, consider the well-known sufficient statistic for this case, $T=X_{(n)} = \max_i X_i$. The support of this statistc is $[0,\theta]$, and hence I can make the same point: how is the conditional distribution $f(\mathbf{x}|t;\theta)$ of $\mathbf{X}$ conditional on $T=t$ a constant function of $\theta$ since it's not even defined for $\theta = t/2$?

Comment: Maybe you should consult the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Uniform_distribution).

Comment: I've read it but it doesn't answer my question. That's kind of the point I was trying to make in the question: most books/articles/etc kinda go around the issue, by giving this usual definition and then almost immediately stating the Fisher's factorization problem (which doesn't suffer from the issue I have with the original definition, even though they are supposed to be equivalent). With Fisher's factorization problem, you don't really have to worry about the support because you are not diving anything.

Comment: On the other hand, when you claim (in the original definition) that the conditional distribution $f(\mathbf{x}|T(\mathbf{X})=t;\theta)$ does not depend on $\theta$, then I ask: what if for a specific choice of $\theta$ that conditional distribution is undefined? Because after all, $f(\mathbf{x}|t;\theta) = \frac{f(\mathbf{x},t;\theta)}{f(t;\theta)}$. But if $t$ is not in the support of $T$ (which can depend on $\theta$, like in my example), then $f(t;\theta) = 0$ and hence $f(\mathbf{x}|t;\theta)$ is undefined...

Comment: If you are interested, I found the answer to my question I suppose. The more rigorous definition (in the measure theory sense) does address the issue I mentioned by basically imposing that it's not the conditional distribution of $\mathbf{X}|T(\mathbf{X})=t$ itself that needs to be independent of $\theta$, but what they call a *version* of it. Anyways, here's a [link](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177730032) on an article that rigorously defines it this way (page 232, definition 5).

Comment: @user45453: You could write those details up and then answer your Q yourself

Answer (score 2):

The most frequently seen example of this is $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim\operatorname{iid} \operatorname{Uniform}(0,\theta).$ It is said that the conditional distribution of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ given $\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ does not depend on $\theta.$

But to be precise, it ought to be said that it does not depend on which of the values of $\theta$ consistent with the observed value of $\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ is the true value. Then one would take that to be the definition of sufficiency of the maximum.